# is there any limit/role for `syn` initial number and `seq` number of TCP three-way handshake?

Tags: tcp, networking

We know the TCP three-way handshake, I want to know is there any limit/role for `syn` initial number and `seq` number?

[image]

I hear about the number set random can protect server, who can help talk about this?

Comment: What's your aim?

Comment: I mean whether the syn and seq number must set to 1? in fact whether they are usual random for security?

Answer (score 3):

`syn` control flag should be set to `1` and `seq` should be generated randomly in the first step of connection establishment as described below.

RFC 793 indicates about sequence number that:

> Sequence Number:  32 bits
>
> The sequence number of the first data octet in this segment (except
> when SYN is present). If SYN is present the sequence number is the
> initial sequence number (ISN) and the first data octet is ISN+1.

Also, RFC 6528 indicates that:

> We can prevent sequence number guessing attacks by giving each
> connection -- that is, each four-tuple of (localip, localport,
> remoteip, remoteport) -- a separate sequence number space.  Within
> each space, the ISN is incremented according to [[RFC0793]](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc0793); however,
> there is no obvious relationship between the numbering in different
> spaces.